# Why Do I get an Invalid syntax in python terminal when trying to open Django files from Documents folder.

Tags: python, django, terminal

I am running Python 2.7.3 and I just installed django 1.4.3. I am trying to open the file 
    cd ~/Documents/Projects
but I get an error that reads in total....
   cd ~/Documents/Projects
    File "", line 1
    cd ~/Documents/Projects
       ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Is it something to do with PATH directories being messed up? I have no idea I am a Newbie. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

cd is a shell command, to change dir in python you need

```
import os
...
os.chdir('path/to/directory')
...
```

where `...` is your code

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run shell commands *inside* Python.  Python doesn't know what `cd` is.  You need to do that from inside a plain command prompt, where you have a prompt that looks like `C:\whatever\> _`.